# Removing lines that do not provide connectivity using FME

Tags: line, fme-form, remove

I have two datasets one for lines and another for polygons, the lines data that contains lots of small line segments that are not needed. I would like to delete the lines only if they are not connected to another line or polygon and only leave in the lines that provides connectivity. I would like to do that using FME but I'm struggling to find the right transformers, any leads please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on a workstation so I can't test at the moment, but I would try a SpatialRelator, candidates only, test for 0 or 1 relate.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.